# Reverse engineering Python Executable with unknown compiler

Tags: python, python-3.x, reverse-engineering

I have a python script compiled to an EXE without the knowledge of the compiler that was used.
I've been searching for an answer for a while but I can't seem to find anything about this.  Most, if not all only show how to decompile Pyinstaller or py2exe using scripts that are on Github and some are just outdated. However, I have attempted something different. Like code execution through the application but from what I have tried, none have worked.

I've attempted [PyMem](https://github.com/srounet/Pymem), and [Pynject](https://github.com/am-nobody/pynject) along with some others.

pymem:

```
import pymem
import subprocess
try:
    mem = pymem.Pymem("test.exe")
except:
    subprocess.Popen("test.exe")
    mem = pymem.Pymem("test.exe")

mem.inject_python_interpreter()

code = """
import os
os.system("cls")
print("some text")
# or anything really, I've tried to write functions or even print/write __file__ then nothing happens
"""

mem.inject_python_shellcode(code)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried any static analysis strings, etc. to try to find indicators of the compiler used?

Comment: I believe it's Nuitka by the way the package was compiled.